# Pyspark dynamic frame adding extra blank columns for no reason

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

Whenever I load a file and I print the schema, it displays a bunch of blank columns labeled col4-col89 (your numbers may vary), and when I write to csv, it shows the extra blank columns.

Example of my code:

```
%pyspark
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

def changeSex(rec):
    if rec["sex"] == "m" or rec["sex"] == "M":
        rec["sex"] = "Male"
    elif rec["sex"] == "f" or rec["sex"] == "F":
        rec["sex"] = "Female"
    else:
        rec["sex"] = "Unknown"
    return rec

output_path = "s3://my-bucket/outputs/test"
print("Data schema before maps")
df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
       database = "my-db",
       table_name = "my_bucket")
df.printSchema()
connection_options = {"path": output_path}
new =  Map.apply(frame = df, f = combineNames)
new.printSchema()
print("Data schema after maps")
new.write(connection_type="s3",connection_options=connection_options, format="csv")
```

A truncated version of my output looks like this:

```
Data schema before maps
root
|-- first: string
|-- last: string
|-- sex: string
|-- col4: string
|-- col5: string
|-- col6: string
|-- col7: string
|-- col8: string
```

even though my schema in my table only has 4 columns. Why does this happen and how can I clean this up?

Also a bonus question that's slightly related. When I write to s3, it generates 3 files whose file names I can't control. Is there a way to control the file names (I can only set the path, and doing something like my-bucket/outputs/output.csv creates a folder called "output.csv")

Comment: please add your table schema and source file data as well.

Comment: also avoid using hyphen(-) in database or table name as it is not supported on Athena, so you wont be able to verify the data on athena either.

Answer (score -1):

About bonus question:

```
df = new.toDF()
df.coalesce(1).write.format('csv').save('s3://my-bucket/outputs/test/output.csv')
```

About original question: `create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` works fine. I need more details to understand issue. Can you share table schema from glue catalog and also how you created it? My bet will be on the fact that Glue Catalog itself is having all blank columns.